# If $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $g\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $f\star g=0$ a.e. then $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $g\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $f\star g(x)=0$ a.e. Then show that $f=0$ a.e. Note, $g$ is a fixed function.

So from the given condition I can see $\hat{f}(y)\hat{g}(y)=0$ for every $y\in\mathbb R$ so $\hat{f}(y)=0$ or $\hat{g}(y)=0$ for every $y$.

I now thought of applying the uncertainty principle. The set $\{y:g(y)\neq 0\}$ is bounded, hence $\{y:\hat{g}(y)\neq 0\}$ must have infinite Lebesgue measure, in particular must be unbounded. So $\hat{f}(y)\neq0$ over a set with infinite measure. So what?

Comment: You'd better rule out $g = 0$.

Comment: you also have $f*g^n(x) = 0$ where $g^n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative.

Comment: But how does that help?

Comment: An approach you can try is if $F(g)(y)=0$ in an closet set $y \in S=[a,b]$ ($F(g)$ is the fourier transform of $g$) then since $(I_{[a,b]} F(g) )(y) = 0$ we can write $(g*sinc)(x) = 0$. So you have to rule out $(g*sinc)(x) = 0$. Now if you let $a$ closer to $b $ until center positive part of sinc function becomes wider than support of $g(x)$. Now if $g$ is positive, this gives a contradiction. So if $g>0$ then i think you can prove it.

Answer (score 4):

We can say much more about $\hat{g}$ than just that it is nonzero on an unbounded set.  In particular, we can say that $\hat{g}$ is analytic (indeed, it is an entire function if we let its input range over $\mathbb{C}$).  This means that if $\hat{g}$ is not identically $0$, its zeroes are isolated (and in particular form a set of measure $0$).  So we must have $\hat{f}=0$ a.e., and so $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: Oh okay, I did not know anything about the analyticity. Haven't got to that part yet in class.